# Formastic and attribute_methods_generated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having an Issue with Formastic and Ruby On Rails
Here is the run down
Ruby and Rails info

- Ruby on Rails 3.0.7
- Ruby 1.9.2p180
- Formtastic 1.2.3
  Here is the error

  undefined method `attribute_methods_generated?' for nil:NilClass

Controller

```
def new
   @assignment = Assignments.new
   @title = "Sign Up"
end
```

View

```
<% semantic_form_for(@assignment) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
    <%= f.inputs :name, :duedate, :class, :priority, :grade, :descrption, :points_value %>
   <%= f.submit "New Assignment" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have typos and reserved keywords in your example.
you may want to check this again.

":class" is a reserved keyword, I suppose and "descrption" (typo)

Comment: Oh, yeah, I also forgot to post that the line that rails is having an issue with the first line. Thanks!